# SDN 4.1 - Multithreading Neo4j TestServer for parallel execution of test cases

Tags: neo4j, spring-boot, junit4, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I'm using org.neo4j.ogm.testutil.TestServer and the http driver for integration testing instead of the Embedded driver because I like how the TestServer provides a browser based interface to see what is happening with each test.

However - my tests take ages! The build is getting up to around 30 minutes on a reasonably quick machine.

What I'd like to do is use the maven surefire plugin to execute my test cases in parallel.

To do this I imagine I'll need to be able to startup several neo4j TestServer instances, each on a different port.

Where is the best place to do this using neo4j 4.1? I assume @Before and @After (for shutdown) methods of my test cases? (possibly extracted into a super class?)

Also, how would I get the current port for the current test context into each unit test?

Any suggestions of how to go about this would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `org.neo4j.ogm.testutil.MultiDriverTestClass` which sets up the Driver using the TestServer. 
The TestServer should pick an available port anyway which should solve your problem of setting these up in parallel. In fact, you can just have your test class extend `org.neo4j.ogm.testutil.MultiDriverTestClass` (most of the tests in org.neo4j.ogm.persistence.examples do this) and provide an `ogm.properties` file that specifies that the driver to be used is the HTTP Driver

```
driver=org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver
```